# Linking to Nested Object from Index Template in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to link to a post from it's index template, but can't quite figure out the dynamic link-to arguments. It would seem that I need to pass a `topic` argument as shown below, but I'm not sure how to get to the topic from this route.

**Template**

```
{{#each posts in controller}}
  {{#link-to 'post' topic post}}<h4>{{post.title}}</h4>{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

**Router**

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('topic', { path: '/:topic_id' }, function(){
    this.resource('posts', { path: '/posts' });
  });
  this.resource('post', { path: '/:topic_id/posts/:post_id' });
});
```

**Route**

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('posts');
  },
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render('posts'), {
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're each statement is wrong, you have it as `each posts` but then you're using `post`.

```
{{#each post in controller}}
  {{#link-to 'post' topic post}}<h4>{{post.title}}</h4>{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

Additionally I'm not sure where `topic` comes from.  If I were to guess I'd say it was probably on the parent controller.  In that case you'd need to reference the controller hosting that model.  To do that in the Posts controller you'd need to setup a `needs` allowing the controller to talk to the other controller's

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   needs: ['topic']
});
```

Then in your template it would be like this

```
{{#each post in controller}}
  {{#link-to 'post' controllers.topic.model post}}<h4>{{post.title}}</h4>{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```

Or if you wanted to make it a little prettier

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   needs: ['topic'],
   topic: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.topic.model')
});

{{#each post in controller}}
  {{#link-to 'post' topic post}}<h4>{{post.title}}</h4>{{/link-to}}
{{/each}}
```